# Should I put my getter functions inside or outside my functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I have a React functional component that uses a `useState` hook:

```
const [options, setOptions] = React.useState({
  a: true,
  b: 10,
  c: 'asdf'
})
```

If `options` is more complicated of a structure and I want to write functions to which I can pass this object and get some properties out of it, is it better to write those functions inside the functional component, or put them outside and pass them the `options` object?  If I have a bunch of these inside, these functions will get re-created each render right?

```
// put this inside the functional component, or outside?
function getSomeComputedValue(options) {
  return Object.keys(options.someNestedObject).filter(o => o.status === 'cool')
}
```

Comment: With regards to the function getting recreated every render you could wrap it inside React.useCallback and specify the dependencies for when the function should be recreated. If the dependencies stay the same the function will not be recreated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should put out side when your function **only depends on it's parameters**.

Why? Because if that function will never change, you don't need to recreate it on every render. You could also put it in a utils file or something like that if you need to use in another component.

> If I have a bunch of these inside, these functions will get re-created each render right?

Yes, there is no need to recreate the function on every render if you don't need for it to change.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends, If you are going to use that function in different components, yes, put it outside maybe in a shared or util folder. It depends because the output of that function may depend on the change of the component state, so you may use useMemo or useCallback as you need it.